# Can you show that $3n+1$ is not divisible by $5$ using congruences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove that the difference of two consecutive cubes is never divisible by $5$, and I got to a point where I would have to prove that $3n+1$ is not divisible by $5$, where n is an integer. This problem is from a section that deals with congruences and that's why I'd like to know how to show that 3n+1 is not divisible by $5$ using congruences. There might be better ways to solve the actual problem, but for know I'm just interested in the $3n+1$ part.

Comment: But have you actually checked this for some values of $n$? Say 3 for example?

Comment: @AritraDas The change to $3^n + 1$ was NOT by OP. I have rolled back that edit.

Comment: @Soke Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: My apologies, that was a wrong edit of mine. But $3n+1$ is not a difference between consecutive cubes either.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yea, there was definitely an issue with getting from $(n+1)^3 - n^3$ to $3n+1$. The $3n^2$ term was left out.

Comment: @Soke or maybe he did what I commented on your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n = 3 \Rightarrow 3n+1 = 10 \equiv 0 \mod 5$. The steps you took to get to this point were not valid.

The difference of two consecutive cubes is $(n+1)^3 - n^3 = 3n^2 + 3n + 1$. A systematic way to check if this is ever divisible by $5$ is to check for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. If none of these are, then the quantity is not divisible by $5$ for any integer $n$. Why?

Any integer can be written as $5m + n$ where $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $$3(5m+n)^2 + 3(5m+n) + 1 = 3(25m^2 + 10mn + n^2) + 3(5m + n) + 1 \equiv 3n^2 + 3n + 1 \mod 5.$$

Comment: How come it's enough to just check for 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: @user265554 Updated

Comment: I think I now realise what mistake the OP made. In $3n^2+3n+1=3(n^2+n) +1$ OP assumed $n^2+n=t$ so that now he had to prove $3t+1$ isn't divisible by 5. What he failed to realise that $n^2+n$ doesn't take all values in $\mathbb{N}$. You might want to include that in your answer.

Comment: @user265554 I'm curious, what step did you make to get to $3n+1$? Was it just an algebraic mistake or did you do what Artira Das is saying?

Answer (score 2):

$$(n+1)^3-n^3=(n+1-n)((n+1)^2+n(n+1)+n^2)=3n^2+3n+1$$

$n\equiv0 (\bmod5) \Rightarrow 3n^2+3n+1\equiv1 (\bmod5)$

$n\equiv1 (\bmod5) \Rightarrow 3n^2+3n+1\equiv2 (\bmod5)$

$n\equiv2 (\bmod5) \Rightarrow 3n^2+3n+1\equiv4 (\bmod5)$

$n\equiv3 (\bmod5) \Rightarrow 3n^2+3n+1\equiv3 (\bmod5)$

$n\equiv4 (\bmod5) \Rightarrow 3n^2+3n+1\equiv4 (\bmod5)$